# Improper integral (using methods in complex variables)

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration

Let $0<a<1$. Evaluate the integral

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{a-1}}{1+x} dx.$$

Comment: Only thing that comes into my mind right now is, $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \cfrac{x^a}{x(1+x)}dx = \int_{0}^{\infty} \left(\cfrac{x^a}{x} - \cfrac{x^a}{1+x}\right)dx = \int_{0}^{\infty} \left(x^{a-1} + \cfrac{x^a}{1+x}\right)dx $$

Comment: Please add your own work to the question to avoid getting downvoted. That will help the users to answer the question to your level.

Answer (score 3):

All integrals of the form $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\frac{x^{a-1}}{1+x^b} dx~$ can be evaluated by substituting $t=\dfrac1{1+x^b}~,~$

then recognizing the expression of the [beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) in the new integral, and employing

[Euler's reflection formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula) for the [$\Gamma$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Properties) to rewrite the final result as $\dfrac\pi b~\csc\bigg(a~\dfrac\pi b\bigg)$.